# MDX Query to get employee ID based on their login ID

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm trying to implement dynamic security on a cube where an employer should be able to see the measures associated with all the employees under him.

I'm doing this by first getting the login credentials of the logged in user using `USERNAME()` and then getting the descendants of that user.

However , I'm having an issue because the descendants in the employee dimension are defined on `empID` attribute whereas the `USERNAME()` gives the login ID attribute.

I'm not able to use descendants function on Login ID attribute.

i.e

`{DESCENDANTS(STRTOMEMBER("[Employee].[Emp ID].&[3]"), , SELF_BEFORE_AFTER)}` works  but

```
 {DESCENDANTS(STRTOMEMBER("[Employee].[LoginID].&[abc]"), , SELF_BEFORE_AFTER)}
```

doesn't work.

So , how can I get the `empID` attribute based on the login ID ?

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for achieving this. One of the solutions is to set `LoginID` as NameColumn for `[Employee].[Emp ID]` attribute and then use the following query.

```
SELECT  
    {} ON 0,

    DESCENDANTS(
                FILTER
                (                    
                    [Employee].[Emp ID].MEMBERS,                     
                    [Employee].[Emp ID].CURRENTMEMBER.NAME = USERNAME()
                )                   
                ,                   
                ,SELF_BEFORE_AFTER                  
                )              
           ON 1

FROM [Your Cube Name]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I'm using roles , I was just trying to make up a query first in ssms and then put it in the roles allowed set. Btw , I managed to achieve what I was trying to by using name column just like Akshay mentioned. I set Login ID as the name column and instead of using & operator used . operator in my query. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done via a dynamic Role, not in a query.

Using a role will lock in the user and when looking at empID they would only see numbers for those that are mapped to their login.

This is one of the better explanations for this concept:http://richardlees.blogspot.se/2010/10/ssas-dynamic-security.html?m=1

Another reason to fix this in the cube role is that your data is not secure if you just do it via query. Anyone will be able to connect to the cube via excel and browse all emploee data.